# sending POST to php server not working

Tags: php, ios, objective-c

My iOS dev is sending a POST request from iOS to our API (which is processed with some PHP and looks for $_POST).  However, on the API end, it's seeing the POST as empty.  And instead, it's seeing the data as GET.  Any ideas?

On my end, I'm simply checking if $_POST is not empty...

```
if(!empty($_POST)) {
    // process request
} else {
    // POST is empty
}
```

Here is the code my iOS dev is using.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:CREATE_USER_URL, SERVER_KEY, usernameFormatted, emailFormatted, passwordFormatted]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *guid = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] globallyUniqueString];

[SMServiceConnection makeRequest:request
                       requestor:requestor
                        callback:callback
                             guid:guid];
```

Comment: What does your final URL look like? Also, you do not show where you set the request body (`[NSMutabelRequest setHTTPBodt:]`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not setting the POST body, try [`[NSMutableURLRequest setHTTPBody:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSMutableURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableURLRequest/setHTTPBody%3a) with some data you like to send to the server.

Comment: oh my... can't believe we overlooked that!